# Search out of order terms

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

[image: example]

I have a Search Bar with a Tableview and I am able to search:

- "2695"
- "2695-650"
- "2695 650"
- "São João"
- "sao joao da talha"

And get the following result:
2695-650, São João da Talha

However, if I search the terms out of order like this:

- "sAo joA da TaLH"
- "sao talha"
- "talh joa"
- "joao talha"
- "talha 650 joao"

I get a list of empty results.

How can I adjust my search to include out of order terms?

Comment: Add the code you've tried so far.

Comment: You should look for "fuzzy text search" libraries, like http://iosexample.com/simple-and-fast-fuzzy-string-matching-in-swift/ or https://github.com/krisk/fuse-swift and others.